# Paginated UNION ALL result - best performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We have a situation where we need results from 4 different tables combined into one list and paginate it through OFFSET/FETCH.

What want to select records from tables a, b, c & d, order them by CreatedDatetime and then OFFSET X, FETCH Y. Tables are quite big (in terms of numbers of rows) and it sounds horrible to do just UNION ALL and then pagination because it would mean probably compiling whole list of records and then taking paginated part.

Problem is that none of the tables can be taken as reference to extract Start/End Datetime window because every collection might but also might not contain records from any of the table. For example, ending result might contain records from any combination of tables `a; a/b; a/b/c; a/b/c/d; b; b/c;....` and we need fixed size number to be returned (paging size, for example, being 20).

Any ideas on how to most effectively approach this?

**UPDATE**

Based on question from @HABO
There are unfortunately no special clues like that about queries. We are showing user activities in the system. There are different kinds of it (tables we select over). Now, query pops up data for administrator who views the activities. How administrator will look at data may vary drastically: some users will have thousands of activities in last few hours and admin will want to see them all. In other cases, users will have 3 actions in a day and admin will see just first page of data.

PS. It's not a pure log tables as activities act as state machines over time, each having their states, which we also look for in these queries.

Comment: does the data HAVE to be real time?  would an Indexed View suffice?  the waiting overhead is pushed to off hours and the index on the view can provide the performance you're looking for.  It simply Moves/hides the wait of the unions to a more appropriate time.

Comment: well, thats a good question. if it would be done that way then it would not be a problem and if there is no other solution we would go the way you propose. but for now i'd like to see if its possible to do it in a real time in acceptable manner.

Comment: i mean, we could go probing by adding some assumptions, for example, that going 5 hours backwards will yield 20 results and if it doesn't, go back in time more...but that's not really SQL...

Comment: @xQbert, how could an indexed view help here? `UNION` is a disallowed construct in an indexed view. You mentioned not real time so perhaps you meant a table with the results materialized.

Comment: How about selecting into a #temp.  If you use an iden then you can use that for the OFFSET X, FETCH Y.

Comment: @DanGuzman and I learn something new.  I Guess it would have to be a self managed table.

Comment: Any more clues about the paging, e.g. it rarely goes beyond 100 rows requested over a period of five minutes? Are there any parameters associated with the query, e.g. `ShoeSize`, or are all requests interchangeable? You could cache the top _N_ pages when a request is made and, to the extent possible, return results from the cache. Cache entries greater than _M_ minutes old can be deleted. That means you may return stale, but recent, data.

Comment: @HABO I have updates my question. Please find answer to your comment there.

Comment: @deezg Where you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

if you know the page size (eg 100) then you can simply write 4 Top 100 queries (order by Create Date) - Then do a Union ALL on the result.
That way even if all the first 100 records come from 1 table you are covered.

For Subsequent Paging queries - You'll need to record the last displayed row from each table and use this as your High-Water mark for the next fetch - (Select top 100 FROM TableA Where RowID > @HighWater)

Should be fairly efficient...

Comment: This sounds very promising, i like the approach! Will try this one definitely. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

This is where a **cache** comes in useful. You can either cache the result of the query in your application layer and do the paging there if it is not too large, or cache the results of the query in a table (or temp table) if it is large.

Answer (score 0):

There would be filters i suppose. From what you say, those may vary a lot. So at the worst scenario, all columns can be filters.
My suggestion is to use 5 views, one for each table and a final one union them. Just make sure all filter columns go up the physical tables as straightforward as possible.
Finally, select the master view and fetch but be careful of the order by clause. Make sure order by has unique data combination else you might have cases where a row change pages on a simple plain refresh. If there is user order by defined, force add some key columns at the end.

How to safely ensure order by to have distinct values for 100% safe fetch/offset:

At the 4 views create a new column with a simple constant number as value, e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4 AS [TableSource]
Make sure you select the PK of each table. If you don't have, you have to create one in the views, probably using ROW_NUMBER or NEWID, as [Pk] for example.
Finally, when selecting from the master view, you ORDER BY CreateDate, Pk, TableSource. This way you are 100% safe that within the same set of data any row will be placed exactly at the same position, resulting correct paging.

Example of safely isolating a page of 30 rows order by CreateDate:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT src, id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY dt DESC,src,id)rn FROM (
SELECT 1 src, id, dt FROM table1 /*WHERE x=y*/ UNION ALL 
SELECT 2 src, id, dt FROM table2 /*WHERE x=y*/ UNION ALL 
SELECT 3 src, id, dt FROM table3 /*WHERE x=y*/ UNION ALL 
SELECT 4 src, id, dt FROM table4 /*WHERE x=y*/)alltables
)data WHERE data.rn BETWEEN 3001 AND 3030
```

Comment: the problem is how to limit those 4 views? to what datetime back to look within each view?

Comment: You don't need to filter by date unless you actually have user filter. Else, supposing the user filter e.g. by IP, how you filter also by date? Won't this wrongly limits the results further? Unless of course there is an agreement e.g. 1 or 2 years data. In this case you can, although it is better to archive the tables themselves.

Comment: There are other filters, of course, but datetime is always present. So, we need datetime ordering regardless of other filters state. Imagine infinite set of users activities and whatever filter you apply, you will always need 30 activities ordered by datetime.

Comment: Filters are for performance. The CreateDate is for standard order by from what i see, to result to proper paging. That is ok, if all tables have a CreateDate column and the 5th view union that column to a final CreateDate column, you can order by and fetch-offset. This however is not 100% safe, a record may change pages (+1 or -1) if it has exact the same CreateDate value with 1 or more rows. See my reply for solution.

Comment: i must admit i've read your answer 10 times and i am not sure i understand the benefit of views in this example. I understand what you mean around losing records on the page breaks, but that's a separate problem. What i don't understand is how view help performance in this case since you don't know how many records to load into each view in the first place. Or are you suggesting putting whole tables in their views? If latter, then i dont understand the gain with views. **please note:** i'm not trying to prove your suggestion wrong; on a contrary, i want to make sure i am not missing something.

Comment: I have done this about a dozen times on sql 2014 the last year and performance was improved significantly. Same setup as you describe, a complex report on large tables, with paging (plus filters for me on every result column). For example i have a master view with 26 joins (including full outer and nested) and works really fast. To be honest i do not had that case yet (4 physical tables needed to union somehow), but what i described would be my first attempt. If you can afford it (i cant because i follow the framework) you can certainly build a custom SP do the job as smart as possible.

Comment: let me try to phrase a question like this, just for the sake of discussion: if you would have 4 tables, each having 20 million records out of which you would need to get combined, paged collections of strictly 30 records per page ordered by datetime - would you use views? and if so, what exactly would you put in each view? whole tables selects? (for the sake of discussion, please assume user has chosen no filters at all)

Comment: and yes, i am definitely looking into custom SP. that doesn't exclude views solution, of course, if they can help in any way.

Comment: i try 4 tables just now (76, 19 16 and 13 million rows) with the statement i update above and took 30 sec to find a page. my 70 million table does not had a datetime field at all so i had to build one (catastrophic) so i guess it would respond faster on your system with normal (indexed?) datetime or date fields.

Comment: yes, i would expect it to be aroud those times. i would definitely like to lower that down substantially :)